# ActiveAdmin customizing the form for belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have these associations:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :signup
  has_many :user, :through => :signup

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signup
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :signup
  has_many :course, :through => :signup

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signup
end

class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, I would like to customize the ActiveAdmin form for "Signup", so it shows the title of the courses and the name of the users as a select and not as a textfield.

The default form already does that, however I need to customize the form further and I can't reproduce the default form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form block will look something like this in your `admin/signups.rb`:

```
form do |f|
    f.input :course
    t.input :user
end
```

By default, since `course` and `user` are associations, this should give you a `collection_select` - that is, a with the `name` attribute of your models as labels, `id`s as values. If you had passed your `input`s a input type, this will force them to display as that type.

```
form do |f|
    f.input :course, :as => :string
end
```

This'll just give you a `course_id` text input field, where you'll probably just enter the ID for the associated object. To "reproduce the default form", just continue adding `input`s for the relevant attributes. You can even wrap them in `f.inputs` to group them and make things look pretty.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Basic Details" do
        f.input :course
        f.input :user
    end
end
```